# How to find out acceleration from space dependent velocity function?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, vector-fields

Suppose I have a velocity function V = ui + vj + wk; where u,v,w are functions of x,y,z and i,j,k are unit vectors mutually perpendicular to each other. Then what is acceleration of this velocity function?

Is it necessary to calculate three components( acceleration along x,y and z-axis) independently or there is a way to directly obtain acceleration using vector calculus?

Comment: Either way, independently or vector - same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Acceleration is obtained using material derivative used in fluid dynamics, usually written $\frac{D\textbf{V}}{Dt}$. For a general velocity field we have
\begin{align}
\frac{D\textbf{V}}{Dt}\equiv \frac{\partial \textbf{V}}{\partial t}+\textbf{V}\cdot\nabla\textbf{V}
\end{align}
In your case $\frac{\partial \textbf{V}}{\partial t}=0$. See that acceleration in any one direction depends on velocity in all three directions.

Comment: This Du/Dt gives?

Comment: The first equation is the definition of the material/substantive derivative. You were correct in your comment below: for steady flow, the acceleration is given by the chain rule, which in turn gives $\mathbf{u}\cdot\nabla\mathbf{u}$.

Comment: @SulavSigdel I am not sure what your question in the comment means. When you said you have velocity field, you must have meant velocity of something (particles, fluid, motorbikes?). Du/Dt gives acceleration of that something.

Comment: I get that. But why acceleration along x direction depends velocity in all three direction? I mean not mathematically but physically.

Comment: @SulavSigdel It is difficult to explain without drawing a figure. Imagine a uni-directional velocity field, inclined at 45 deg to X axis. Also velocity increases along that direction. It could be an accelerating flow inside a convergent pipe. Now as fluid particle moves 45 deg to X axis it accelerates along that direction (due to its velocity in that direction), which acceleration has a component along X axis, as well as Y axis. This is a trivial example to be sure, but you should draw more complicated vector fields and verify it yourself.